# Why does this function have a tangent line at x=0?

Tags: calculus

$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\sqrt x&\text{if $x\ge 0$}\\
-\sqrt{-x}&\text{if $x<0$}
\end{cases}$

The graph around $x=0$ looks like this:

[image]

When I derive $\sqrt x$, I get $\frac12 \sqrt x$. I replace $x$ with $0$, which gives me $0$.

Comment: $x=0$ is an equation for a vertical line.

Comment: The derivative does not exist for x=0, the slope is undefined (+/- infinty) for x = 0 confirming the vertical line as the tangent.

Comment: @imranfat my book says (answer to an exercise) that it has a tangent line and that line is x=0. I answered that it is undefined. I'm confused.

Comment: x=0 is the equation for the y-axis and that's the vertical tangent to the curve

Answer (score 2):

You derived wrong. The derivative of $\sqrt x$ is the derivative of $x^{1/2}$.

Comment: You should have 1/[2*sqrt(x)]

Comment: @EhBabay, that's the same as $$(x^{1/2})'=\frac12x^{-1/2}\ldots$$

Comment: @DonAntonio, I suspect hir comment was really on the question rather than my answer.

Comment: @dfeuer yes, thanks for pointing that out. I derived right when I wrote it down on paper but on this math forum I got it wrong. I'm not used to this Latex formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative  of $\sqrt{x}$ is $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$.